# Reemplazar una string solo si esta no se encuentra precedida por un patrón especifico y simultáneamente no se encuentra sucedida por ese patrón

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, str-replace

porque este script hecho en python

```
import re

texto = ", y SRYIUILEP , y  SRYIUILEP jhjhjhj  BRYIUILEV , y SRYIUILEP khkoo ohoh, y  SRYIUILEP "

#combino el lookbehind y lookahead negativos en un solo patrón
patron = r"(?<!SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)\s*,\s*y(?!\s*SRYIUILEP|\s*BRYIUILEV|\s*LPRYLBVDA)"
#patron = r"(?<!SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)\s*,\s*y(?!\s*(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))"

reemplazo = " &, y& "

nuevo_texto = re.sub(patron, reemplazo, texto)
print(nuevo_texto)
```

no da este resultado con los reemplazos:

```
" &, y&  SRYIUILEP , y  SRYIUILEP jhjhjhj  BRYIUILEV , y SRYIUILEP khkoo ohoh &, y&   SRYIUILEP "
```

y en su lugar da este output erróneo en donde directamente no hace ningún reemplazo, aunque esto esta mal porque en este ejemplo hay 2 ocasiones en donde sí se cumple la condición para que el reemplazo sea realizado.

```
", y SRYIUILEP , y  SRYIUILEP jhjhjhj  BRYIUILEV , y SRYIUILEP khkoo ohoh, y  SRYIUILEP "
```

En objetivo es que reemplace `",\s*y"` por `" &, y& "` solo si `",\s*y"` no tiene delante alguna
de estas strings `SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA` por lo que intente utilizar un lookahead negativo, y que a la vez que `",\s*y"` no este sucedido por alguna de estas opciones `SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA` por lo que intente utilizar un lookbehind negativo.

El grupo `(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)` se utiliza para combinar las opciones del lookahead negativo y del lookbehind negativo, y utilizando `?:` en lugar de `()` para indicar que se trata de un grupo sin captura.

Que debería cambiar en mi código para obtener el output correcto?

Comment: La expresión hace lo que pides en el título. Reemplazar solo las partes que no tengan ninguna de esas palabras ni antes ni después. Es contradictorio con el ejemplo que das. Replantea la expresión o explicate mejor.

Comment: Yo creo que en realidad quieres exactamente lo contrario. https://regex101.com/r/XgFQWx/2

Comment: @Mateo He editado el ejemplo, para que se vea mas claro, porque tenias razon en que habia un error cone ste. Ahora si, los ", y" que no estan en medio de esos patrones deben ser reemplazados, aunque la regex no lo hace, ya que simplmente no hace nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partimos de la base de un regex con los 2 patrones (`pre` y `post`)

```
(?P<pre>SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)\s*,\s*y\s*(?=(?P<post>SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))
```

en el que hicimos que `post` sea un lookahead para que no consuma ese texto, y que de esa forma esté disponible para coincidir con el siguiente reemplazo.

Luego, hacemos que los 2 patrones sean opcionales con `?`:

```
(?P<pre>SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)?\s*,\s*y\s*(?=(?P<post>SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)?)
```

Ahora, lo único que tenemos que asegurarnos es que no haya coincidido con **ambos** en la misma coincidencia... Y eso lo podemos hacer dentro de una función en cada reemplazo.

Código:

```
import re

texto = ", y SRYIUILEP , y  SRYIUILEP jhjhjhj  BRYIUILEV , y SRYIUILEP khkoo ohoh, y  SRYIUILEP "

regex = r"(?P<pre>SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)?\s*,\s*y\s*(?=(?P<post>SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)?)"
reempl = " &, y& "

def no_pre_y_post(m):
    if m.group("pre") and m.group("post"):
        # coincidió con pre y post
        # reemplazar por todo el texto
        # (que es lo mismo que no reemplazar)
        return m.group(0)
    else:
        # coincidió, pero pre o post no estaban
        # dejar pre como estaba
        # e insertar el nuevo texto de reempl
        return (m.group("pre") or "") + reempl

resultado = re.sub(regex, no_pre_y_post, texto)

print(resultado)
```

Resultado:

```
&, y& SRYIUILEP , y  SRYIUILEP jhjhjhj  BRYIUILEV , y SRYIUILEP khkoo ohoh &, y& SRYIUILEP
```

Answer (score 2):

Si te he entendido bien **,\s*y**  no deben estar entre **(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)**, por lo tanto, pueden darse los siguientes casos:

1. precedida por *a* pero no seguida *a* (a b !a)
2. no precedida por *a* pero seguida de *a* (!a b a)
3. ni precedida ni seguida por *a* (!a b !a)

para **a**=*(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)* y **b** = *,\s*y*

Transformando cada caso en un expresión regular, tenemos:

*Caso 1:* ((?:(?<=(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))(?:\s*,\sy\s+))(?!(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)))

*Caso 2:* ((?:(?<!(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))(?<!\s)(?:\s*,\s*y\s*))(?=(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)))

*Caso 3:* (?<!(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))(?<!\s)(?:\s*,\s*y\s*)(?!(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))

Si juntamos los tres casos, tenemos la expresión regular que requieres:

```
((?:(?<=(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))(?:\s*,\sy\s+))(?!(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)))|((?:(?<!(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))(?<!\s)(?:\s*,\s*y\s*))(?=(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA)))|(?<!(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))(?<!\s)(?:\s*,\s*y\s*)(?!(?:SRYIUILEP|BRYIUILEV|LPRYLBVDA))
```

Aplicando esta expresión a lo siguiente:

```
, y SRYIUILEP , y SRYIUILEP jhjhjhj  BRYIUILEV , y SRYIUILEP khkoo ohoh, y SRYIUILEP, y lksajdlkasj, y jdjalñjsdkl, y BRYIUILEV, y sdañjad skñsñldaks
```

y aplicando el reemplazo, resulta en:

```
 &, y& SRYIUILEP , y SRYIUILEP jhjhjhj  BRYIUILEV , y SRYIUILEP khkoo ohoh &, y& SRYIUILEP &, y& lksajdlkasj &, y& jdjalñjsdkl &, y& BRYIUILEV &, y& sdañjad skñsñldaks
```

Espero sea lo que requieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias por presentar los 3 casos posibles, yo estaba intentado por el caso en que **ni precedida ni seguida por a (!a b !a)** , pero los otros 2 me sirven de referencia tambien